# OpenSSO remote SP and Password as Authentication Context

Tags: metadata, saml-2.0, opensso

I use OpenSSO and I've created remote SP based on metadata file. I'd like to use Password as an Authentication Context for this SP but don't know how to tell OpenSSO to do that. OpenSSO gives me ability to configure it for the hosted SPs created from scratch but for remote one created base on metadata file I don't have it. How can I configure that? Default Authentication Context for my IdP is PasswordProtectedTransport, and I don't want to change it because I have other remote SP which are using this context. But I'd like to use Password context only for the one SP I'm describing here.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to specify in the AuthnRequest what authentication context you want, in your case

```
<saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext>
    <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password
    </saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
</saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext>
```